# Getting SSL Error When I ran API Https Request

Tags: python

I am Getting below error when I ran the request.

> SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Can any one help me out to resolve the issue.

Issue exists in Python 2.7.7. It's working fine in 2.7.3?

Comment: This doesn't say much. Can you tell what method/module are you using to send the request?

Comment: You should also add your request

Comment: (and welcome to Stack Overflow!). Please show us what you've tried previously and that gives us a starting point to help you from

Comment: I am trying to run the Http get request ..